# How can I read input to a String in a separate function?

Tags: rust

I wanted to make a noting application that it could save notes after user closed it. I tried making a ".txt" file and write all of the notes on them. Here is what I did so far:

```
use std::io::stdin;
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn main() {
    let file_name = "dont_open.txt";

    println!("hello wanna take notes?(max 3)");
    let hm = String::new();
    let mhm = String::new();
    let maybe = String::new();

    let _converted_1 = readinput(hm);
    let _converted_2 = readinput(mhm);
    let _converted_3 = readinput(maybe);

    let file_path = PathBuf::from(r"PATH").join(file_name);   

    std::fs::write(file_path, _converted_1);
}

fn readinput(mut input:String) {
    stdin().read_line(&mut input)
        .ok()
        .expect("Failed to read line");
}
```

and I'm getting the:

```
the trait bound `(): AsRef<[u8]>` is not satisfied
the trait `AsRef<[u8]>` is not implemented for `()`
```

Comment: What do you expect `_converted_1` etc. to be?

Comment: Your `readinput` function doesn't actually return anything.

Comment: so rust anylzer makes it :() type I assume thats function and I want to make it string so std::fs::write can read the input

Comment: @isaactfa hm ok so I just need to add "-> String"?

Comment: The `()` value means the statement or the function does not return anything. It is equivalent to the `void` value in C family langs.

Answer (score 1):

To get a result out of `readinput` the argument `input` needs to be changed to a mutable reference:

```
use std::io::stdin;
use std::io::Write;
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn main() {
    let file_name = "dont_open.txt";

    println!("hello wanna take notes?(max 3)");
    let mut hm = String::new();
    let mut mhm = String::new();
    let mut maybe = String::new();

    readinput(&mut hm);
    readinput(&mut mhm);
    readinput(&mut maybe);

    let file_path = PathBuf::from(r"PATH").join(file_name);
    let mut file = std::fs::OpenOptions::new()
        .append(true)
        .open(file_path)
        .unwrap(); // file must exist
    let _ = writeln!(&mut file, "{}", format_args!("{}{}{}", hm, mhm, maybe)); // Result must be used
}

fn readinput(input: &mut String) {
    stdin().read_line(input).expect("Failed to read line");
}
```

…or more ideomatic `readinput` w/o argument:

```
let hm = readinput();
let mhm = readinput();
let maybe = readinput();

fn readinput() -> String {
    let mut input = String::new();
    stdin().read_line(&mut input).expect("Failed to read line");
    input
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok so I did the thing Thanks to @isaactfa I added -> String to readinput and store stdin() to an variable and used added .to_string()

Here is the Final Result :

```
use std::io::stdin;
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn main() {
    let file_name = "dont_open.txt";

    println!("hello wanna take notes?(max 3)");
    let hm = String::new();
    let mhm = String::new();
    let maybe = String::new();

    let _converted_1 = readinput(hm);
    let _converted_2 = readinput(mhm);
    let _converted_3 = readinput(maybe);


    let file_path = PathBuf::from(r"PATH").join(file_name);  
      

    std::fs::write(file_path, _converted_1  );
}

fn readinput(mut input:String) -> String {
    let final_product = stdin().read_line(&mut input)
                            .ok()
                            .expect("Failed to read line");
    return final_product.to_string();
}
```

Comment: Does this work? `read_line` returns the number of bytes read (wrapped in the result) so this will write the length of the input the user gave, not the input itself. I think you want to write `hm`/`mhm`/`maybe`.

Comment: I have issues with this snippet. `readinput` doesn't appear do anything with the provided argument; there is no need for unwrapping the result by first `ok` and then `expect`, a single `expect` suffices; there is no need for an explicit `return` statement.

I suggest reading [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/), and getting familiar with Rust's syntax (whether to include `mut`) and semantics (what it means when you _move_ a variable) and tooling (`cargo fmt` and especially `cargo clippy` really want to help you). Good luck <3

Comment: @Adam The `.ok()` before the `.expect(…)` is superfluous.